# 04 Dodge stratus fluid leak

Tags: coolant, dodge, leak, stratus

Just bought an 04 stratus and after driving for 45 minutes the coolant reservoir was boiling. Added coolant last night and when I woke up there was a leak at the front center of the engine and it won't start. Help!

Comment: How many miles on the odometer?   Has there been any work done to the water pump? thermostat?  radiator?  What is the outside temperature when you see overheating?  Have you looked at other coolant related postings on this website?